# How to get mean value as array of them in numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have image, i need to find its mean color. But np.mean() return me mean value of all elements including rgb values. How to get mean value as array of rgb colors?

np.mean(image) return 6.142314

i need something like this [2.31, 4.4211, 10.01]

Comment: can you provide an example input / expected output?

Comment: `arr.mean(axis=(0,1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [228]: from PIL import Image

In [229]: im = Image.open(filename)

In [230]: arr = np.array(im.convert('RGB'))

In [231]: arr.mean(axis=(0,1))
Out[231]: array([216.57815122, 191.43917359, 211.62774556])
```

using OpenCV:

```
In [238]: import cv2

In [239]: im = cv2.imread(filename)

In [250]: b,g,r = im.mean(axis=(0,1))

In [251]: r
Out[251]: 216.57815122463762

In [252]: g
Out[252]: 191.43917359086018

In [253]: b
Out[253]: 211.62774556460369
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it in opencv?

Comment: @DenisD'yachkov, please check updated answer